# Is there a way to make a decorator or metaclass for a lazily initialized attribute / property

Tags: python

In our current codebase, we have a recurring pattern of:

```py
class Something:
    _client: SomeClientClass = None

    @property
    def client(self):
        if self._client is None:
            self._client = SomeClientClass(**with_some_parameters_from_self)
        return self._client
```

this is required, because

```py
class Something:
    client = SomeClientClass(**with_some_parameters_from_self)
```

leads to problems with pretty much every single widely used client library, as it instantiates the clients at import time.

Is there either an *easy and comprehensible* or *ANY* way to implement this in Python so that the code would look something like

```py
class Something:
    @lazy_property
    def client(self):
        return SomeClientClass(**with_some_paramaters_from_self)
```

This is not the end of the world, and the original code is not exceedingly verbose, but I'm curious if something like this is possible

Comment: How about [`functools.cached_property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property)?

Comment: Is `Something` a singleton by design or does it need to share a class attribute? The "instantiates the clients at import time" is expected, since the code is not happening in `__init__` and is not an instance attribute, but a class one.